# left sticky position not working on smaller screens (keep sticky div width)

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a row with the far left hand item set to `position: sticky` now this works great.. until the screen gets to mobile size and it no longer stays sticky..

**You will need to shrink your browser to see this happen**

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.item {
  min-width: 250px;
}

.sticky {
  min-width: 500px;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item sticky">STICKY</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this??

**The `sticky` div must be `500px`**

Comment: if the sticky element is big enough to match the height of its container then there is no sticky behavior ... add border to your element to notice this

Comment: @TemaniAfif how can I solve this?

Comment: to solve what? you cannot have an element with 500px to stick when the browser is less than 500px. Reduce its height or re-think the logic you want to implement

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `min-width: 500px;` in `css` from your `.sticky` class.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.item {
  min-width: 250px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="item sticky">STICKY</div>
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesnt solve my problem because I want the first div to be 500px